# loop tag misused

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are 12 questions tagged as [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop):

> A loop device allows any file to be mounted as a filesystem image. Not
>   to be confused with a loopback interface in networking.

From those

- 4 are about loop devices,
- 8 are about control flows.

I bring this in attention of moderators as I find the current situation confusing.

As my personal point of view, the [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) tag should remain as is for the 4 loop device questions and the 8 control flow questions should loose their [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) tags.

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember for sure, but I suspect the choice to have [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) mean loop devices rather than control flow is due to programming being mostly off-topic on this site. Loop constructs in shells do come up from time to time, and it's natural to use the `loop` tag in this sense.

Given the wide mismatch between documented meaning and actual use, I've retagged the loop device questions to [loop-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop-device) and copied over the tag wiki.

It remains to be seen what to do with [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop): should it be a synonym of [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow)? Or should it be blacklisted? Note that in addition to being a natural choice for the (rare) questions about loop constructs, it is likely to come up in migrations from Stack Overflow.

Comment: If it's a synonym people will probably continue to use it wrong without noticing. Generally questions from SO need editing anyway, so I'm not worried about needing to add it to questions from them

Comment: Wrong? But if it's a synonym of [tag:control-flow], it's more likely to be used right.

Comment: I mean people tagging [loop] when they mean [loop-devices], which they can't do if there's no [loop] to begin with. I guess hopefully they'll notice the latter in the tag editor

Comment: If [tag:loop] will pertain to `for` and `while` related questions, then would be logic (and politically correct) to also have [tag:conditional] tag for `if` and `case` related questions.

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop)'s tag wiki is about loopback devices, so I left those 4 and retagged the other 8 to [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow). It might be a good idea to change the remaining [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) questions to something like [loop-devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop-devices) to avoid future confusion, but I left it for the moment (anyone with [500 rep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) is welcome to retag them)